# Standard password policy or rules for validating against multiple language

Tags: passwords, multilingual, password-policy

We have achieved internationalization in the application, but now we want to have support for user can enter password in his own language(Arabic, Russian, Chinese) etc. Here the problem is validation gets fail for upper case and lower case characters. So, please help me provide standard validations rules or password policy which can be applied to authenticate user from any language.

Comment: This makes me wonder if attackers use multilingual attack methods, for example do their rainbow tables only include English passwords

Comment: Joseph, currently my question is can you help in getting some standard rules/policy which can be used to validate user which uses any language in password.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at this many years ago, and I've been told that most of the users are using Password that are ascii characters, because it's not possible to compose complex characters (Kanji) without displaying them on the screen.

Also the new recommendations from NIST is to stop trying to impose specific characters, but just enforce a minimal length of at least 8 characters, and check against a dictionary of known compromised passwords.